Installing ROS2 Iron on Windows 11
I followed these instructions to install ROS2 Iron on Windows 11.
When running the example code ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker, I get the following traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Scripts\ros2-script.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.25.6', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')())
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Scripts\ros2-script.py", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\ros2cli\cli.py", line 22, in <module>
    from rclpy.executors import ExternalShutdownException
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from rclpy.signals import install_signal_handlers
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\signals.py", line 15, in <module>
    from rclpy.exceptions import InvalidHandle
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from rclpy.impl.implementation_singleton import rclpy_implementation as _rclpy
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\impl\implementation_singleton.py", line 32, in <module>
    rclpy_implementation = import_c_library('._rclpy_pybind11', package)
  File "C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\rpyutils\import_c_library.py", line 39, in import_c_library
    return importlib.import_module(name, package=package)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclpy._rclpy_pybind11'
The C extension 'C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\_rclpy_pybind11.pyd' isn't present on the system. Please refer to 'https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html#import-failing-without-library-present-on-the-system' for possible solutions

The stack trace is looking for a module named rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.  I believe I was able to find the file it is looking at for at C:\dev\ros2_iron\Lib\site-packages\rclpy\_rclpy_pybind11.lib.  How can I fix this problem?
